# Constructing a chriped dielectric mirror for negative dispersion for ultrashort laser pulses resulting in group velocity delays

Tags: reflection, dielectric

I'm currently looking at designing a chirped mirror for a project but I am confused over several aspects.

I understand the principle of a chirped mirror in terms of how a laser pulse has a broad set of wavelengths and when the pulse arrives at the mirror, there is a frequency dependent refractive index which results in different wavelengths of the pulse being reflected back by the multiple layers of the mirror at different path lengths.

Literature states that these layers are positioned at 1/4 wavelength separations but what does that mean in terms of the pulse? For example if I have a set of 10 layers which are 50nm in length, then what wavelengths of light are reflected on a layer by layer basis? From this, what is the general structure of a chirped mirror in terms of overall placement of layers, starting from how thick the top layer needs to be to the bottom layer and the thickness of intermediate layers.

Secondly, by using a certain number of layers, how does one design a chirped mirror such that It will have a negative group velocity dispersion / group delay dispersion

Thirdly how does phase changes relate to GVD/ GDD?

Finally If I have two dielectric mirror materials, each has a refractive index n1 = 3.0, n2 = 3.5, and a ultrashort duration pulse of the order of 10^-12 seconds, then if I was to construct a mirror using alternating layers of these materials, how many periods would I need to achieve and at what repeating thicknesses a total reflected of the pulse? I know this is somehow related to the path length of the light in these materials but I'm stuck in trying to figure it out. A period here relates to one pair of layer 1(n = 3) and layer 2(n = 3.5)?

Comment: See [chirped mirrors](https://www.rp-photonics.com/chirped_mirrors.html) for a good overview, with literature references.

Comment: This is really close to what I study, which is metamaterials. I can probably have an answer for you in a few days. To give you an idea in the meantime though, the typical design method would be to look at how the periodic structure behaves when all the layers are the same thickness, and there's an arbitrarily large number of layers. This would create a bandgap structure that reflects at certain wavelengths. Then you would slowly vary the period of the structure, and fiddle with the parameters using some kind of software to try and optimize the structure. More layers is almost always better.